# How to reference other functions in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I want to be able to reference other functions inside my script, and then call them. Something like when assigning an on-click event for the button, so I can just drag and drop it in the Inspector. Thanks

Comment: Care to elaborate with a code example of what you want to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to mean a [`UnityEvent`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UnityEvents.html)

```
public UnityEvent someName;
```

and later on at some point

```
someName.Invoke();
```

---

Otherwise just go via your type like e.g.

```
public YourOtherScript example;
```

and then

```
example.YourMethod();
```

Answer (score 0):

you might mean calling a method/function from another class?
Then you could try referencing to that class by doing :

```
private yourclassName yourClassReferenceName;




Public void methodname()
{
 yourClassReferenceName.ThefunctionFromTheOtherClass;
}
```

After you can drag and drop this class on the button and call the methodname(your method).